# Run wbadmin using Console Application

Tags: c#, console-application

i want to run the Windows Backup "wbadmin" using a Console Application.
I am already running the app as an Admin but it still doesn't work.
Anybody already had this problem?

```
string wbadminEvent = " start backup -backupTarget:" + volume + " -include:" + target;
Process objProcess = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo("wbadmin");
start.UseShellExecute = true;
start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
start.CreateNoWindow = true;
start.Arguments = wbadminEvent;
objProcess.StartInfo = start;
```

Comment: Please add your error or exception code to your question. Additionally, `objProcess.Start();` seems to be missing.

Comment: Use the complete path for calling that executable: `new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\windows\sysnative\wbadmin.exe")` on x64 for example..